# Transpose all rows into columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I was asked this question in an Interview and couldn't crack it.
I have a Employee table with following values

```
Id Name  Sal
1  Sid   1000
2  Jon   800
3  Ram   600
```

I want the output to be displayed as follows:

```
 1      2       3
Sid    Jon     Ram
1000   800     600
```

i.e rows to columns.

I used case/decode for the same. But he required different answer as there might be many more columns and he didn't want to use decode for all.
I searched on the net for Pivot and some other functions but wasn't able to make query which could provide me this output. Is it possible to get output in the above mentioned format? If yes can I get the query for this. I am using oracle.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`listagg()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
select listagg(id, ' ')   within group (order by id) as list from employee union all
select listagg(name, ' ') within group (order by id) from employee union all
select listagg(sal, ' ')  within group (order by id) from employee
```

or something like this PL/SQL block:

```
declare
  type lines is varray(3) of varchar2(32767);
  ls lines := lines('', '', '');
begin
  for r in (select id, name, sal from employee) loop
    ls(1) := ls(1)||r.id||' ';
    ls(2) := ls(2)||r.name||' ';
    ls(3) := ls(3)||r.sal||' ';
  end loop;
  for i in 1..3 loop dbms_output.put_line(ls(i)); end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am not supposed to use pl/sql. Also in case if there are 30 columns in a table then according to the given query I would need to use 29 'Union all' which isn't feasible. Is there any other method??

Comment: Hmmm... No `decode`, no unions, no PL/SQL ;-) I don't know the other ways, maybe other users.